# Is it possible to bake fluid simulation into blend file?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

Is it possible to bake a fluid simulation into a blend file, instead of a separate cache folder?

The main reason is, I'm using a renderfarm to upload animation files. The renderfarm only accepts packed blend files and no external folders. I understand it's possible to bake a cloth simulation into a blend file, but not sure how to do the same for a fluid simulation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not that I know of. Fluid caches are so big I'm not sure if this would be practical?

Comment: It depends on the renderfarm you use, ResPower has limited support for fluid simulation see https://www.respower.com/blog/?page_id=193 it also states that packing of a gluid cache isn't possible.

Comment: yes, you can export the simulation as an object sequence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible currently.
I'm not sure how practical this would be, given the massive size of fluid caches.

As [mentioned by stacker](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/is-it-possible-to-bake-fluid-simulation-into-blend-file#comment10320_6472), [ResPower](https://www.respower.com/) supports fluid simulations to some extent.