# Is it possible to store rigid body cached/baked data into an external folder?

Tags: baking, rigid-body-simulation

Is it possible to store rigid body cached/baked data into an external folder, instead of directly in the blend-file so that the file-size is not too large? I feel that storing the data externally seems more convenient, as then I have more control to bake in chunks.

This is an opposite question to [Is it possible to bake fluid simulation into blend file?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/is-it-possible-to-bake-fluid-simulation-into-blend-file)

Similar to rendering an animation to individual frames and convert to video afterwards, so that it is possible to render in chunks.

Comment: The storing is to external folder I mentioned is the same way as baking fluids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no option to bake to external cache.

The workaround would be to convert simulation into an *Action*: *Viewport header > Object > Animation > Bake Action (turn visual keying on)*.

[image]

You can store this action in another .blend to link it somewhere later, or in another file format you can import where you like.

If you want to simulate in chunks, you will have to animate the *Animated* tag under *Rigid Body* settings to control till which point is the last *Action* and where the simulation continues.

Comment: thanks! could you give an example? I cannot find the viewport header